# Two definitions for standard deviation

Tags: statistics

There seem to be two canonical definitions for the standard deviation.
$$\sigma_n = \langle(n - \langle n\rangle)^2\rangle^{1/2}$$
and
$$\sigma_n = \sqrt{\langle n^2\rangle - \langle n\rangle^2}$$

How do we reconcile these two? I've tried expanding $\langle n \rangle = \sum n \cdot P(n)$ to no avail.

Comment: The first one is the variance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance , whose square root is the standard deviation

Comment: Ah, that's my bad. Forgot to add the exponent. Edited!

Comment: I would say that the first one is canonical and the second a derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sigma_n = \langle(n - \langle n\rangle)^2\rangle^{1/2}=\langle (n^2+\langle n\rangle^2-2 n \langle n\rangle)\rangle^{1/2}
$$
and then use linearity of the average to conclude
$$
\sigma_n=(\langle n^2\rangle+\langle n\rangle^2-2\langle n\rangle^2)^{1/2}\ .
$$

Answer (score 0):

With $\bar{x} = Ex$, we have $E (x -\bar{x})^2 = E (x^2 -2x \bar{x} + \bar{x}^2) = E x^2 - 2 \bar{x}^2+ \bar{x}^2 = E x^2 - \bar{x}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proof.
\begin{aligned}
\sigma_n = \sqrt(\sum_i(x_i-\mu)^2)
       & =\sqrt(\sum_i x_i^2 +\sum_i\mu^2-2\sum_ix_i\mu)
      = \sqrt(\sum_ix_i^2-\sum_i\mu^2)\quad (since \sum_i x_i = n\mu$)
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

$\langle(n - \langle n\rangle)^2\rangle^{1/2} = \langle n^2 - 2n \langle n\rangle+\langle n\rangle^2\rangle^{1/2}  = \left(\langle n^2\rangle - 2\langle n \rangle \langle n\rangle+\langle n\rangle^2\right)^{1/2}= \left(\langle n^2\rangle - \langle n\rangle^2\right)^{1/2}$